# Quick beginner XSLT reference

Tags: html, css, wordpress, xslt, symphony-cms

I need to learn XSLT for Wordpress and Symphony theming. What are some beginner friendly resources that are relatively easy to follow along to?

Answer (score 2):

[Mozilla Developer Center's XSLT](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/XSLT)

Answer (score 1):

There are some good symphony specific tutorials here which should help:

http://designprojectx.com/tutorials

Answer (score 1):

This site is very straightforward and has plenty of examples: http://www.learn-xslt-tutorial.com/

Also, W3 Schools is generally easy to follow and has good tutorials: http://www.w3schools.com/xsl/

Answer (score 1):

[ZVON's XSLT reference](http://zvon.org/xxl/XSLTreference/Output/index.html). I like it because it's very simple.

Answer (score 1):

My friend, Roger Costello, makes some of the best tutorials.  He has an nice collection, most of which are XML-related:  XML Schema, Schematron, NVDL, xProc, xPath, xQuery, and XSLT.  They are typically Powerpoint slides and include exercises to give you practice.  Take a look!

http://www.xfront.com/files/tutorials.html

Answer (score 0):

I love this intro / tut from alistapart
http://www.alistapart.com/articles/usingxml/

Answer (score 0):

You can check also :
 - http://www.w3schools.com/xsl/default.asp
 - http://www.w3schools.com/xpath/default.asp

To learn XSLT basics but moreover XPath queries